# Algorithms disappear when I use multicols

Tags: algorithms, multicol, algorithm2e

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{llncs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
  }  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{amsmath}                                
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[boxruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{bl}{rgb}{0.0,0.2,0.6} 
\definecolor{dark-red}{rgb}{0.4,0.15,0.15}
\definecolor{dark-blue}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.4}
\definecolor{medium-blue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks, linkcolor={dark-red},
    citecolor={dark-blue}, urlcolor={medium-blue}
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec} 
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{algorithm}[!h]
\label{alg:quad}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{\textsc{Something} $S$, \textsc{Another thing} $A$}
    do something with $S$\;
    do another thing with $A$\;
\end{algorithm}
\columnbreak
\begin{algorithm}[!h]
\label{alg:cbl}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{\textsc{Something} $S$, \textsc{Another thing} $A$}
        do something with $S$\;
        do another thing with $A$\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The page appears blank.

When I remove `\begin{multicols}...\end{multicols}`, the page returns to normal.

What I'm trying to do is to display those very short two algorithms side by side.
What shall I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`multicol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) complains in the `.log`:

> Package `multicol` Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols' 
>   environment!.

This happens even though you think you're forcing a placement `h`ere in the text, which seems like things shouldn't float. However, as is discussed in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764), placing a float `h`ere doesn't always have the expected output nor does it change it's floating status.

[`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) provides a forced, non-float `H`ere placement though, which provides the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[boxruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \label{alg:quad}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{\textsc{Something} $S$, \textsc{Another thing} $A$}
    do something with $S$\;
    do another thing with $A$\;
  \end{algorithm}

  \columnbreak

  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \label{alg:cbl}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{\textsc{Something} $S$, \textsc{Another thing} $A$}
      do something with $S$\;
      do another thing with $A$\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

---

If you're only after a side-by-side setting of two algorithms, then you can just set them using separate `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[boxruled, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\columnsep}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \label{alg:quad}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{\textsc{Something} $S$, \textsc{Another thing} $A$}
    do something with $S$\;
    do another thing with $A$\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-.5\columnsep}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \label{alg:cbl}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{\textsc{Something} $S$, \textsc{Another thing} $A$}
      do something with $S$\;
      do another thing with $A$\;
  \end{algorithm}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The above `minipage`s are made to fit the original columns with a gap between them equalling `\columnsep`.